# C# Program doesn't work on other computer

Tags: c#, windows

I have made an application that connects to a server and listens to certain packets, I used Nuget network library for that. Here is my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>remote_client</RootNamespace>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64</Platforms>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <StartupObject>remote_client.client</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Network" Version="6.1.4.20" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Management.Automation" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>

  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Then I had problem how to compile it into a **single** .exe file. I found a command I used in powershell (I ran it in project's directory):

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 -c Release /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true
```

And then I had a single file I could use anywhere on my computer. 
When I tried to give it to my friend, it wouldn't work with error from Windows (my translation): Can't run this application. Ask program's developer to do *something...* 
My windows version is 1909 and his is 1809.
So summarizing, I need to fix the issue or get some easy way to publish a application and compile it into a windows-universal single .exe file.

EDIT: actual error message is:

```
This application will not work on your computer. To find the version for this computer, contact the software publisher.
```

First sentence is caption of the popup message box, second sentence is being displayed as message.

Comment: can you post the full error message (the original text instead of something)

Comment: There is not enough information in your question. There are literally hundreds of reasons for this sort of problem, and without more information about your app and what it does it's impossible to help. What do the system event logs say about your app? What specifically does it do? (*connects to a server and listens for packets* isn't specific enough.) What is the **exact** error message? You've also compiled specifically for x64 - is your friend's computer also running a 64-bit system and OS?

Comment: Edited problem and added the error message.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I think that it couldn't work because the computer my friend ran the application on was 32 bit but I compiled it for 64 bit.